# Что делает эта функция?

Tags: java, android

Что делает эта функция?

```
mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
mBackgroundThread.start();
mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
```

Насколько я понимаю Handler нужен, чтоб запускать потоки, но зачем мы передаем getLooper() и что будет происходить в таком случае? как это работает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Handler` выполняет `Runnable` на определенном потоке. В вышепреведенном коде создается поток, на котором будут выполняться `Runnable` при помощи `Handler`. Дальше поток стартуется, и третьей строчкой создается `Handler`, который и будет выполнять `Runnable` на вышесозданном потоке.

Прочитать ,что выполняет определенный метод всегда можно в [оф. документации](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/packages.html)